# Getting the First Word in a Tag With Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, textarea

I'm trying to make a regex to get the first word in a `< ... >` tag. I already have one to get all the words in a tag. I'm using this for it:

```
/<(.*?)>/
```

My question is, can I get the first word in a tag using a regex?

Comment: Is this HTML? If so, just parse it into a document fragment and use `elem.tagName`.

Comment: It's a Parser that uses regex's.

Comment: @user2228462, The accepted solution is wrong. Have a look at my answer to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution: `/<([^>\s]+)[^>]*>/`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it...

```
/<(.*?)\s/
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple case `/<(\S+)/` might be what you are looking for, or you might be more formal and actually list only characters allowed in tag names.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tag = "< hello world>";
var regex = /<\s*(\S*)\b/;

if (match_arr = tag.match(regex)) {
  alert("yes:" +  match_arr[1]);
}
```

> is there any way to get every word after the first word in a tag?

```
var tag = "< hello world goodbye >";
var regex = /<(.*?)>/;

if (match_arr = tag.match(regex)) {
  var str = match_arr[1].trim();
  var words = str.split(" ");
  console.log("-->" + words.slice(1).join(" ") + "<--");
}

--output:--
-->world goodbye<--
```

Comment: Actually, if your string is already just one tag, you can just use the regex: /\b(\S*)\b/ with match().

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by a 'word'.  Is hello="world" a word? Or is that two words?  Are quotes part of the word?