# How do I Find a Literal String Inside Tags with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, textarea

I know I just recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290505/getting-the-first-word-in-a-tag-with-regex), which is very similar, but still different. I'm trying to find all the occurences of this: `" "` within a less than sign, and greater than sign.

You can find anything within tags with this:

```
/<(.*?)>/
```

And you can find a String with this:

```
/"(\\.|[^"\r\n])*"?|'(\\.|[^'\r\n])*'?/
```

How do I find a String within the tags?

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693)

Comment: I never explicitly asked for opinions, or if you should do this; I asked the question: "How to find String literals within tags". I've already read through that, and I winded up asking the question.

Comment: Regexp is really bad for this.  You can find things inside tags by using lookbehind and lookahead. But you can't count quotes, so it can't tell the difference between start and end quote.

Comment: `I never explicitly asked for opinions, or if you should do this` And we suggest that you shouldn't do this, since you taking the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do the trick:

```
/(?:<|\G(?<=(?:<|")).*?(?:>|"(.*?)"))/g
```

See it in action on some random html: http://regex101.com/r/nD3gF4. It could be better, but this will get you started.